# Hiding/Showing ActionBar and BottomBar on content click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, bottom-sheet

I have been trying to do something similar to Kindle app for Android
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.kindle

When you are in the reading Activity if you click content, the ActionBar and BottomSheet animated out of screen. If you click again, they animate inside screen.

I am not being able to make it work using `getSupportActionBar().hide()`
Maybe because I am using CoordinatorLayout

Someone knows how to do it?
Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0):

Try
`getSupportActionBar().hide()` and `getSupportActionBar().show()`

You can check ActionBar state by using `getSupportActionBar().isShowing()` method.

Comment: Yep.. I tried @Metin but it removes all the content of the ActionBar without actually removing the bar itself. The space remains taken by the bar and its background but I see no title or buttons

Comment: It says _Hide the ActionBar if it is currently showing. If the window hosting the ActionBar does not have the feature FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY it will resize application content to fit the new space available._

Comment: Could be not working because Im using a CoordinatorLayout. I will update my question